# Download Image from Url and covert into byte array - android

Tags: java, android, api, android-room

I'm receiving URL of images and other data from API and showing images into recyclerview, I want to store images in room database in a byte array format, but I'm getting an error while converting image URL to a byte array. My app is crashing at url.openstream();.

```
private byte[] getByteArrayImage(String imageUrl) {

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(imageUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        byte[] chunk = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        InputStream stream = url.openStream();

        while ((bytesRead = stream.read(chunk)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        url.openStream().close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: You are calling openStream() twice.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

- As already noted in a comment, you call openStream() twice.
- If an exception occurs, close() won't be called in your code. Use try-with-resources instead.
- Propagate exceptions to the caller. The caller will generally want to know the exception message.
- Don't ever use printStackTrace(). This is the worst way to report errors.
- After the first printStackTrace(), you continue with a null URI, which will cause a NullPointerException.
- The method should be static.

Here's how I would write this:

```
    private static byte[] getImageBytes(String imageUrl) throws IOException
    {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);

        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try (InputStream stream = url.openStream())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

            while (true)
            {
                int bytesRead = stream.read(buffer);
                if (bytesRead < 0) { break; }
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }

        return output.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: It's not working, the same issue crashing at url.openStream()

Comment: This is my example URL = "https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49490420043_1f38e0eac0_m.jpg".

Comment: `getImageBytes("https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49490420043_1f38e0eac0_m.jpg")` works for me.

Comment: Does this action need any specific dependencies or manifest file?